# Can a UITextField become a first responder when it's inside of a UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

Is it possible for a textField that is a property of a UICollectionView to become the first responder, and display the keyboard?

When I use this code, it works for me like 20% of the time.

I've tried calling directly and using the perform selector on main thread method, no dice.

I've tried resigning other responders before the textField becomes the first responder.

Am I calling the first responder in the wrong place?

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    self.nameField.delegate = self;

    [self.nameField addTarget:self action:@selector(nameFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

    [self.nameField performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay`. The `awakeFromNib` method is called early in the initialization sequence. It's not the right place/time to be setting the first responder.

By calling `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` with a delay of `0`, you allow the initialization process to finish before attempting to change the first responder.

Comment: This worked for my first cell that showed up in the collection view, but not the second cell that came afterwards, which is of a different type. But good point about the init process!

Comment: My bad, I had the userInteractionEnabled boolean in the xib disabled. As soon as I enabled that, it started working, thanks!

Comment: Just as a note, I used a delay of ```1```, wasn't working with ```0``` for me for whatever reason.

Comment: The ```awakeFromNib``` method seems to be called after the ```init``` methods. Would this affect the contents of your answer?

Comment: @NYCTechEngineer I would need a lot more information about how your app works. Ideally, an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), although I realize that's difficult if you're using storyboards.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you shall make your customCollectionViewCell's `textField` become first responder in the method:  `- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: I'm not selecting a cell, but merely presenting it.